# Convergence of infinite series over prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the following sum:

$$\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\frac{1}{p},\mathcal{P}=\{p|p\equiv1(\mod3),p\mathrm{\ is\ a \ prime \ split \ in\ } \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})\}$$

**Question:** Is this sum convergent or divergent? I doubt that the partial sum grows as $c\log\log x+A(c=1/6?)$, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Do you know another way to characterize the primes that split in that field?

Comment: @GerryMyerson:$4p=a^2+243b^2$,I think?

Comment: y_zhao, correct, and Cebotarev density says that these primes have a (nonzero) natural density among the set of primes, meaning the sum of reciprocals diverges. See David A. Cox, Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2.$

Comment: See also Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/inhom.html